# Adding Child Data to the Product Flat Index

Tags: magento-enterprise, indexing, flat-catalog, magento-1.14

**Summary**: Is there any action required to pull data from "child products" into configurables on flat tables other than setting `global/catalog/product/flat/add_child_data` to 1?

> App: *Magento 1.14.2.4*
>
> Action: *Reindexing Catalog Product Flat table with n98-Magerun*

More detail follows...

In order to pull a configurable products associated simple data into the flat table, I have set the config value of `global/catalog/product/flat/add_child_data` to '1'.

This configuration value is read by `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_Flat::isAddChildData()`, which itself is used by `Enterprise_Catalog_Model_Index_Action_Product_Flat_Refresh::_createTemporaryFlatTable`, `Enterprise_Catalog_Helper_Product::getFlatColumnsOldDefinition` and others. These classes use the predicate to properly generate the structure for the resulting flat table, and the temporary indexing tables.

The problem I'm having is that the Product Refresh Model's `_fillTemporaryFlatTable` method attempts to insert into the temp table (which now includes `child_id`) without providing data for that column. This occurs even though that column has a FK constraint on the `catalog_product_entity` table. Needless to say, the attempted insert fails with a scary-looking `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation` message. This is occurring during an n98-Magerun `index:reindex catalog_product_flat` run.

So far, I've searched DDG and Google for both (and variations on)

> ["add_child_data"](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22add_child_data%22)

and

> ["isaddchilddata" magento](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22isaddchilddata%22%20magento)

but none of those searches yielded useful results. The closest to useful result I found was [this](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2015/06/10/magento-flat-tables/) blog post by the Excellence Magento Blog. The following excerpt summarizes my goal:

> ‘global/catalog/product/flat/add_child_data’ : if this is set to 1, two column are added ‘is_child’ and ‘child_id’. Both these store relationship between configuration, grouped, bundled and its associated simply product.

Here's what I've found so far:

1. When enabling `add_child_data`, `child_id` and `is_child` are added to the flat columns used in the temporary and resultant flat tables
2. However, adding child data *does not* appear to affect the select statement that reads from various product attribute tables
3. This results in a foreign key constraint violation where the `child_id` column isn't present in the data which would be "inserted from select"

I'm primarily looking at `Enterprise_Catalog_Model_Index_Action_Product_Flat_Refresh::_fillTemporaryFlatTable` right now, trying to figure out where in that method (or a previous one, maybe?) the `child_id` data would be added to the select.

Thanks a bunch for reading. Hope this makes some sort of sense!

Answer (score 1):

So, if you are using attributes for configurable products and you want those attributes to be shown in the flat tables, you need to have the attributes configured so that they have the **used_in_product_listing** set to **TRUE**

This will then add the columns to the flat table assuming that you have the flat catalog product options set to Yes in the system config.

Don't forget to re-index, and refresh cache.

Checkout: http://docs.magento.com/m1/ee/user_guide/catalog/attribute-frontend-properties.html

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, the issue isn't related to standard Magento EAV attributes. That I'm aware of, `child_id` isn't an attribute that can be configured to be included in flat tables. More importantly, the issue occurs _before_ `used_in_product_listing` would be helpful.